docker-compose not working on ubuntu 20.04
The docker-compose command not working on Ubuntu 20.04 latest using the Ansible task.
It was working on 21 May but not working now.
The command for reference [ Trying from ansible task ]:
sudo SERVER={{bootstrap_server}} docker-compose -f {{ service_base_path }}/{{ docker_file_name }} up -d

Getting the following error:
"KeyError: 'http+docker'"

Note - I have already checked for permissions
Docker versions ->
"docker-compose version 1.25.0, build unknown" 
"Docker version 24.0.5, build 24.0.5-0ubuntu1~20.04.1"

After upgrading using "pip install --upgrade docker", getting error:
"TypeError: kwargs_from_env() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ssl_version'"] 


Just FYI, Docker Compose v1 has been deprecated since 2023. I don't know if this is the cause of your trouble, but just know you're asking about unsupported/deprecated software. You should for all valid reasons consider upgrading your systems to support Docker Compose v2.

This might be a bit late... but better late than never. I had this same issue. I am on ubuntu 20.04 and my docker-compose version was set to be v1.24. The solution to the "KeyError: 'http+docker'" issue was to upgrade to v1.29.
Hope this helps anyone in the future...

This seems to originate from the pip package requests since version 2.32.0.
I had a similar issue (not in docker-compose) and worked around it by "pip install requests==2.31.0".
Here are other solutions: https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/3256
